# Can I target full framework and use Azure func runtime version 3

Tags: azure-functions

To use Azure Func, Can I target full framework instead of .Net Core, and use Azure func runtime version 3?

Comment: I think it is impossible. Azure function v3 is based on .net core 3.0. If you want to target full framework, you should use azure function v1.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible. Azure function v3 is based on .net core 3.0. If you want to target full framework, you should use azure function v1.

Have a look of this offcial doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions

By the way, azure function v2 is based on .net standand at first. But anyway, you can not target full framework except using azure function v1.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot target full framework instead of .NET Core and use Azure Functions runtime version 3.

If you need to target full framework, you will need to use Azure Functions runtime version 2.x or earlier. However, Azure Functions runtime versions 2.x and earlier are no longer supported and have reached the end of extended support. This means that they will no longer receive security updates or bug fixes.

[image]